# My program isn't running, multidimensional vector function

Tags: c++

I have a problem, we all do sometimes.
My program (which I'll use for academic purposes) isn't running, I'm new to programming. What should I modify?

I can't correct the errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
//Maximul din triunghiul de deasupra diagonalelor unei matrice
int maximdiag(int x[5][5])
{
    int i, j, m = 5, max = 0;
    //elementele din triunghiul de deasupra diagonalelor
    for (i = 0; i < (m - 1) / 2; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < m - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (x[i][j] >= max)
                max = x[i][j];
        }

    return max;
}

void main()
{
    int a[5][5], z, n = 5, i, j;
    //citire de la tastatura matrice
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("x[%i][%i]= ",i, j);
            scanf_s("%i", &a[i][j]);

        }
    //apelare functie
    //z = maximdiag(a[5][5]);
    printf("Valoarea maxima din triunghiul de deasupra diagonalelor este a[%i][%i]= ", maximdiag(a[5][5]));
    _getch();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "program isn't running"? Does it not compile? What's the compiler error then? Or does it not run as expected?

Comment: The problem is the use of `maximdiag(a[5][5])` in the `printf` call. Use `maximdiag(a)`. The compiler should report that as an error.

Answer (score 1):

`maximdiag(a[5][5])` calls the `maximdiag` with the element of the array `a` at the index `[5][5]` (which doesn't exist).

To pass the array to the function simply call: `maximdiag(a)`.

You are also passing a single argument to `printf` with a format string which expects 2 arguments. Presumably the corrected code should be something like:

```
printf("Valoarea maxima din triunghiul de deasupra diagonalelor este a[%i][%i]=%i ", i, j, maximdiag(a))
```

Though the values of `i` and `j` will simply be 5 so you need to return them from your `maximdiag` function if you want to get the indexes of the maximum value:

```
int maximdiag(int x[5][5], int& maxI, int& maxJ)
{
    int i, j, m = 5, max = 0;
    //elementele din triunghiul de deasupra diagonalelor
    for (i = 0; i < (m - 1) / 2; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < m - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (x[i][j] >= max)
            {
                max = x[i][j];
                maxI = i;
                maxJ = j;
            }
        }

    return max;
}

int maxI;
int maxJ;
int max = maximdiag(a, maxI, maxJ);
printf("Valoarea maxima din triunghiul de deasupra diagonalelor este a[%i][%i]=%i ", maxI, maxJ, max);
```

Comment: Thankiessssssssssssssss